# Libtool: link: unable to infer tagged configuration

Tags: c, linux, libtool

I am trying to cross-compile linphone for ARM. I configure it using

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --with-gnu-ld --disable-static --disable-glib --with-osip=/home/user/linphone_wheezy --with-readline=/home/user/linphone_wheezy SPEEX_CFLAGS="-I/home/user/linphone_wheezy/include" SPEEX_LIBS="-L/home/user/linphone_wheezy/lib -lspeex" SPEEXDSP_CFLAGS="-I/home/user/linphone_wheezy/include" SPEEXDSP_LIBS="-L/home/user/linphone_wheezy/lib -lspeexdsp" CC=$CROSS_TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --disable-video --enable-gtk_ui=no
```

The configure script executes successfully, but when I run make, I get the following error while linking:

```
libtool: link: unable to infer tagged configuration
libtool: link: specify a tag with `--tag'
```

I have tried adding

```
--tag=CC and --tag=LD
```

but no success. Can someone give some hint on this error?

Comment: Using same commands but changing the Cross-compile toolchain resulted in this error: "/usr/bin/ld: .libs/mscommon.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)". Why is it using host linker instead of cross-compile toolchain's linker?

Answer (score 0):

default command: `/bin/sh libtool ...`

I edited makefile which line of defined libtool to `libtool --tag=CXX`

CXX for C++, CC for C

reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Tags.html